# Is the green route on the airport chart drawn correctly according to the pilot-tower conversations? I do not think so

Tags: air-traffic-control, aeronautical-charts, ground-operations, holding, taxiways

I think the green route in the tower pilot conversations is drawn incorrectly. Here the "UNTIL LEFT HOLD SHORT FOR M29" part confuses me. I would be glad if you help.[image]

Comment: Your picture is too poor of a resolution to be able to answer.  My first impression is that if M29 is the NW to SE section of taxiway that the left fork towards the West end of M could be labeled "Left M29".  The route as drawn makes sense.

Comment: Yes, but I confused about the holding point. If the ground says "UNTIL LEFT HOLD SHORT FOR M29", where should the pilot stop and wait for the next instruction?

Comment: Because pilot does not turn into the M29 holding line with left turn in the picture.

Comment: @MichaelHall [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCFec.png) is a higher resolution picture of the area in question.

Comment: @Bianfable Thank you for high-resolution chart.

Comment: I agree it looks confusing.  Maybe the controller wanted them to stop adjacent to the M29 hold point and not proceed all the way up to hold for Y10?

Comment: This is exactly what needs to be said. But I am confused as it is not found in pilot-atc conversation. If it happened as you said, they should have also joined the conversation above. Thanks for your opinion, sir.

Comment: But I think that's exactly what they are saying, just not in a way that either you or I might have phrased it.  That happens.  Someone familiar with the airport and any local practices may be able to actually answer, otherwise we can only make an educated guess.

Comment: What is the source of the transcript? It is clearly inaccurate. The controller probably said "continue to the left," not "until left," and there may be other errors. What is the 3rd language that appears in a few places in parentheses?

Comment: The source is one of the instructors from my Flight School who I can not contact, so routes and conversations may be incorrectly worded or specified. That's why I am asking. The language in parentheses is Turkish, the language spoken in the country I live in. Some greetings in local languages have been translated into parentheses so that we can understand them.

Comment: @pilot162 OK, thanks. (Odd that "vielen Dank" is spelled correctly in one place but then wrongly ["filen dank"] in another. I think the transcript has to be considered unreliable.)

Comment: Unless the transcript is reliable, this question is meaningless. What is the source of the transcript and the sketch - some unreachable somebody?? Why would the question even matter? Far too many comments & unanswered questions with far too little relevant substance - VTC.

Comment: I'm with you Ralph, I think we can only speculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing punctuation.

"CONTINUE UNTIL LEFT HOLD SHORT FOR M29"

should be

"CONTINUE UNTIL LEFT-HOLD-SHORT FOR M29"

It is a reminder to watch for the holding intersection on the left. As a minor intersection, it might not have a stop line.